# Simpler way of solving multivariable differentiation

Tags: calculus

Let $z = e^{x} cosy $, where x and y are functions of t defined by:

$x^{3}+e^{x}-t^{2}-t=1$

$yt^{2}+y^{2}t-t+y=0$

Find $dz/dt$

---

I have solved this problem already, but i am not sure on how to simplify it as I get a really messy expression when trying to solve it at the end. Firstly, i have:

$\displaystyle\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1+2t} {3x^{2}+e^{x}}$

And:

$\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1-2yt-y^{2}}{1+2yt+t^{2}}$

And this is my other expression:

$\displaystyle\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dt}e^{x}cosy-e^{x}siny\frac{dy}{dt}$

Or can someone check if I derived the expressions correctly? Thank you.

Comment: $\LaTeX$ tip: it is nicer to use `\cos` instead of `cos`. Compare $\cos$ and $cos.$ Similarly, `sin` and `tan` are nicer.

Comment: In your formula for $\frac{dy}{dt}$ you have a $dy$ in place on an $dx$, I think.

Comment: There might be a clever way to simplify it using the equation connecting $x$ and $t$ and the equation connecting $y$ and $t$  but I can't see it.

Comment: So the better thing to do is just leave it as an extremely big expression? (I've tried solving the terms independently and they don't cancel out or anything)